# How to find when the password for my Active Directory user account will expire?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I will be out of office next two weeks. May I check from my domain member workstation when exactly the password for my Active Directory user account will expire. I use Windows 8.1. My user don't have administrative rights to domain controller.

Comment: use `net user %USERNAME% /domain`

Comment: The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain mycompany.com

System error 1355 has occurred.

The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
 I use VPN  to my office.

Comment: You have DNS issue. Do you have ping to mycompany.com?

Comment: Thanks for fast response . I had DNS problem and after restart of VPN I got information from my domain. Thanks again for everyone!